# How to submit html to Solr not over http

Tags: java, solr, indexing

I am using SOLR 4.6 for indexing and now i have large amount of stored html files.
I tried  to add these files to SOLR over http or curl but it's taking much time.

Anyone knows how to submit files for indexing directly to SOLR? I have these files on server where I have my SOLR running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though answer provided by Okke Klein is good but its much complex.

I found the simplest solution for the problem i am submitting the file over http but with the option stream.file=local_file_path

Example :-

```
curl http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?stream.file="+file.getPath()+"&literal.id="+id+"&commit=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to index all the files. There is also a HTMLStripTransformer if you want the content cleaned up,

Comment: This is more complex to implement i found easy way explained below